# EF Core: duplicated foreign key in migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

It's my first project with using Entity Framework Core and sometimes the relationships are a bit confusing for me. The problem is when I'm creating a database migration, it always add foreign keys I haven't defined. So I can't use the database because inserting new values throws a duplicated entry exception.

But first some code of my config:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<SignatureToUser> Signatures { get; set; }
}

public class SignatureToUser
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int SignatureToUserID { get; set; }

    public int SignatureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("SignatureID")]
    public virtual Signature Signature { get; set; }

    public string SignatureUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("SignatureUserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And that is the builder options I use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SignatureToUser>().HasOne(l => l.User).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SignatureToUser>().HasOne(l => l.Signature).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SignatureToUser>().HasIndex(l => l.SignatureUserID).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SignatureToUser>().HasIndex(l => l.SignatureID).IsUnique(false);
```

And now the problem: this is the generated migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "SignatureToUser",
            columns: table => new
            {
                SignatureToUserID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                SignatureID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                SignatureUserID = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_SignatureToUser", x => x.SignatureToUserID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_SignatureToUser_AspNetUsers_SignatureUserID",
                    column: x => x.SignatureUserID,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_SignatureToUser_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

As you can see there is a foreign key `UserId` added as a duplicate to my already existing key `SignatureUserID`.

How can I disable the creation of this additional foreign key?

In my research, I also heard about base classes could be a problem. Is this still a problem? I also tried something like that to trick the base class, but there were no changes.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get { return base.Id; } set { base.Id = value; } }
}
```

Thank you for reading :) I hope anyone has an idea

Comment: So you've defined the FK using Data Annotations and also using Fluent.. ? Also, minor curio; have you created a middleman table between two entities that are related 1:1 ? How many signatures can a user have? How many users can a signature have?